# Pasting serial numbers to existing entries from a forloop in laravel

Tags: laravel, loops

I am trying to batch input a number of items, once they are in the database I want to add a unique suffix to the end of the item name. As an example:

[1]Item becomes Item-0001

[2]Item becomes Item-0002 etc....

I have this code at the moment:

```
        $initial = Batches::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first();
        $batch = Inventory::where('production_id', '=', $initial['batch'])->get();

        $production_code = $initial['batch'];
        for ($i=0; $i<($data['quantity']); $i++){
          $index[]=$i;
        }
        $batch->each(function ($item, $index) use ($production_code) {
          $item->update(['item' => $production_code . '-'.$index]);

        });
```

This works and labels each of the items however it will only add it like so:

Item-0

Item-1
etc..

I would like to find a way to specify the suffix that is added and the starting number, in this case 0001.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just add some leading Zeros:

```
sprintf('%04d', 1); // = 0001
sprintf('%04d', 113); // = 0113
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [sprintf()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) function:

```
sprintf("%'04d", $index);
```